# How can I extend a shower curtain to close a gap at the floor?

Tags: bathroom, shower

My shower curtains fall a little bit too short (like 4cm / couple of inches) and in consequence there is a lot of splash on the floor on the other side of the curtains. Sometimes, it's really wet.

I have to mention that I'm talking about a Finnish shower —I'm living in Finland — so there is not shower tray. It's just the bathroom floor leaning a little bit so the water goes to the sink on the floor.

The curtains are held in place with a rod and of course the obvious solution would be lower the rod. However, we are renting and we've talked with the company owning the building and told us that there is no posible. I guess they don't want to make more holes in the wall.

On the below image you can see the kind of hooks the curtains have.

[image]

Wondering if anyone around here has a great solution for this problem or there is nothing I can do.

Thanks!

PS/ The ideal situation is to have the curtains at 1cm or 0.5cm so they are close enough, but they don't touch the floor. If the curtain is touching the floor, mold in the curtains it's going to develop sooner or later.

Comment: Did you know those curtain hoops are upside down?  They are supposed to go around a simple rod and slide over it.  The narrow part goes on the curtain, the wide part goes around the rod.  Maybe the curtain grommet makes that impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I would buy a second set of those white plastic loops and drop the curtain down easily that way.

Comment: Yeah… that's a solution too… but I was thinking in something more elegant. I mean, they are aligned now. With a second pair of hooks they are are probably going to be twisted.

Comment: Then buy curtains that are longer - and they are available.

Comment: yeah… 20cm, I just need 4cm. It's just the guys that installed the curtains didn't really installed with a 2m curtains on them. In the previous house we were living they were just perfect.

Comment: So what you seem to want is houses built to match your shower curtain...  btw you can cut a long curtain shorter...

Comment: No… shower curtains in Europe are usually 2m —the most common ones— and then you can get 2.2m if you look around but they are rare. When you install the rod, the best way is to do it with the curtains on place, so are able to install them as close as posible to the floor without touching. I guess I'm asking too much?

Answer (score 0):

Get a second shower rod that's white and tension adjustable so no new holes. Install it below the existing one and reverse the existing hoops so the round part has the rod passing through it and the small dip holds the curtain.

See example below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, you have 3 options:

1. Buy a longer curtain, it may be too long, which is fine. You can bring this curtain to just about any seamstress and they will cut it down and hem the bottom for a "factory" look at whatever height you want.
2. Try to find longer/larger rings. This may not be possible to get *exactly* the size you want, but it could get you closer. You might also try using zip-ties as an adjustable "ring extension".
3. Move the curtain rod down. Depending on how it is secured this may range from impossible to "needs paint work" or a more difficult patching job. It doesn't look like the rod you have is one of those pressure rods (that screw out and press against the walls).

*Bonus option:
If you have a 3D printer, you could easily design curtain loops for whatever size you need.